# help proving function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f\in O(C)$ be entire function. Assume there is a disk $D_r(z_0)$ such that $f(C)\cap D_r(z_0)=\emptyset$ prove that f is constant.

I need help starting the proof. I tried to using Liouville theorem for complex holomorphic functions but got stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : what can you said about $$g = \frac{1}{f - z_0} ?$$

Comment: it has no zeros and holomorphic

Comment: Yes, but here maybe Liouville could be useful too ?

Comment: If you need one more hint, remember that by hypothesis $|f - z_0| > r$

Comment: alright. so absolute g is bounded thus constant. which makes f bounded by choice of function.

Comment: Yes, but here we don't know yet if $f$ is bounded : we don't need it, because $g$ constant $\Rightarrow$ $f$ constant.

Comment: that makes sense. thank you N.H.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Another exercise about Liouville's theorem : suppose $f$ is a complex holomorphic function $\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ with $\Re(f)$ bounded, then $f$ is constant.